# How to import cookies to selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I tried adding cookies using `driver.add_cookie()` and passing entire line as an argument, but it didn't work, my cookies look like that

```
.google.com     TRUE    /   FALSE   1678918203  SEARCH_SAMESITE CgQIs5YB
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   TRUE    1679506673  VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE  -JTWPhbwbcc
```

Answer (score 0):

To use cookie you need use directory and place name-value appropriately. Here is an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

cookie_dict = {"name": "key", "value": "value"}

driver.get("http://www.youtube.com")

# Adds the cookie into current browser context
driver.add_cookie(cookie_dict )
```